# Download internet browser for windows ce

Tags: windows-ce, motorola

I have a Motorola MC2180 device running CE6 and for some reason it did not come with Internet Explorer.
Where can I download a version of an internet browser that runs on CE. Please, if possible direct me to the download rather than just suggesting a browser that may work. I've been trying different browsers for a while, but none of them have a .cab file installer that I can run on CE.

Thank you.

Comment: Microsoft should have one if there's one available for CE6. This question is off-topic for StackOverflow; there's nothing in it even vaguely programming-related. Please take a few minutes to review the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for info on what questions are (and are not) proper for this site. Thanks. :-)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be available separately, you'll need to contact Motorola.

Comment: Ken - I'm programming on the device and I need IE on the device hence the question, and to answer your comment on Microsoft having one, yes indeed they have one just that it does not seem to be freely downloadable.

Comment: Mark - Thanks for a constructive answer. I thought so too, I'm reaching out to Motorola now. Mods, please free to close this out if this is in violation.

Comment: @Rakesh, its not quite that easy.    MS doesn't provide CABS like this for every processor/variation of a OEM CE build.   Motorola will have had to provide/port IE as part of their specific platform variation of CE (in this case, Xscale with the 2180's specific hardware requirements.)

Comment: The question is off-topic because it is about general software and not related to programming. For the same reason as the question "Why doesn't Windows boot on the computer I use for programming" is off topic. Furthermore, questions asking for links, tools, libraries or other off-site resources are also off topic.

Comment: Note that deleting this question would break a [link only answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e02e30f3-ec96-4128-a6c1-70f6997b7a7f/internet-explorer-for-windows-ce-60?forum=windowscompatibility) on social.microsoft.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll not find a download for IE because Windows CE is a modular OS.  Simply providing the IE is not enough, as it requires a lot of other OS-level dependencies that may or may not be there.  There's no way to provide a new coredll.dll that contains those required pieces in a download, it has to be built and fixed up for your target.  IE also changes the license SKU from Core to Pro in 6.0, so it would be a licensing problem as well.

If you want IE, you'll have to ask Motorola for a new OS image that creates it.  If you don't care exactly which browser you have, then follow @yms's advice and look at [Opera Mobile](http://www.operamini.com/mobile/download/versions/), [MiniMo](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/minimo/), or one of the [other browsers with CE support](https://superuser.com/questions/24263/is-there-a-free-internet-browser-available-for-windows-ce).

Comment: Thanks - I called Motorola and they gave me an alternate browser to use (Rho elements browser)

Answer (score 2):

The MC2180 does not have IE, because comes with Windows CE CORE edition, this ed. does not contain IE, the MC2180 is an economic range solution. They are other solutions available according to your needs.

-Motorola Technical Support Engineer

Answer (score 1):

You could try with [Opera Mobile](http://www.operamini.com/mobile/download/versions/). It may work on your flavor of Windows CE 6.0.

Comment: Thanks - I tried Opera Mobile, the downloads (.cab) I tried did not run on Windows CE, comes up saying file not supported on Win CE. I had to call Motorola and they gave me an alternate option.